# Coefficient of $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-..-x^{d-1}}$ and its asymptotic

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

> Let $C_n$ be the set of all compositions of n such that each letter is one of ${1,2,\ldots,d-1}$.

> A. Calculate the generating  function of the number of compositions in $C_n$.

> B. For each composition $\pi \in C_n$ define  $f(\pi)$ as the number of letters that equal $1$.
> Find yhe generating function of $\sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{\pi \in C_n}  q^{f(\pi)} x^n$.

> C.Find the expectation of the number of letters that equal 1 (1's appearances) in these compositions, and analyze it *asymptotically*.

*Generally: Composition of $n$: a sequence of numbers in $N$ such that their sum equals $n$. For example:
$C_0={\epsilon}$ , $C_1={1}$, $C_2={11,2}$ , $C_3={111,12,21,3}$.

In this question, a composition of a number $n$ , consists of numbers from the set {$1,2,\ldots, d-1$} where $d$ is a given number.

This is what I did:

A. Every compisition of n = empty compisition $\cup$ (1 / every compisition) $\cup$ (2 / every compisition) $\cup$....$\cup$((d-1) / every compisition).
so if x counts the length of a number, then the  generating function $C(x)$ for the problem satisfy:

$C(x)=1+xC(x)+x^2C(x)+\cdots+x^{d-1}C(x)$

(1 for the empty compisition)

$C(x)=1+C(x)(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{d-1})$

Therefore, $C(x)=\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^d}=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-...-x^{d-1}}$

B.Let $q$ counts the appearances of 1 and $x$ as we mentioned counts the length of a number.
Then:

$C(x)=1+qxC(x,q)+x^2C(x,q)+\cdots+x^{d-1}C(x,q)$

$C(x,q)=1+C(x,q)(qx+x^2+\cdots+x^{d-1})$

So, $C(x,q)=\frac{1-x}{x^d+(q-1)x^2-(q+1)x+1}$

C. We have to calculate $[x^n]C(x,1)=[x^n] C(x)$ and $[x^n] ([(d/dq) C(x,q)]_{q=1})=\frac{x}{(1-x-x^2-...-x^{d-1})^2}=xC(x)^2$ so the expectation will be the proportion of them.

But I could not see how the coefficients can be calculated!
I did not succeed to connect it to Fibonacci series which I know (the case of d=2).

I would be thankful for any help to show part C.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Few comments. $$
C(x) = \frac{1}{{1 - x - x^2  -  \cdots  - x^{d - 1} }}
$$ is the generating function of the Fibonacci $(d-1)$-step numbers. There is an explicit formula for them but it is not so nice. Also $$\left[ {\frac{{dC(x,q)}}{{dq}}} \right]_{q = 1}  = xC^2 (x).$$

Comment: If you set $F_0^{(d)}  = F_1^{(d)}  = 1$, $F_k^{(d)}=0$ for $k<0$ and $F_n^{(d)}  = F_{n - 1}^{(d)}  + F_{n - 2}^{(d)}  +  \cdots  + F_{n - d}^{(d)}$ for $n\geq 2$, then $$
\frac{1}{{1 - x -  \cdots  - x^d }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {F_n^{(d)} x^n } .
$$ You should be able to obtain this generating function the same way you derive the one for the Fibonacci numbers ($d=2$). I did not find this version online, sometimes they shift the indexing which alters the generating function slightly. To obtain the asymptotics of $F_n^{(d)}$, you need to do a singularity analyisis of the gf.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, Must I look at the exponential g.f of $\frac{1}{1-x-...-x^d}$? @Gary

Comment: Which part you do not know how to do? To prove the generating function, just multiply both sides by $1-x-\cdots-x^d$, use the recurrence of the numbers, and you should end up with the identity $1=1$.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to implement this because this is pretty much complex algebra to me, but the bounty interested me. We shall figure it out.

Comment: @Gary , is it possible to get the coefficient with Fibonacci series. Since I did not understand how..

Comment: Your biggest problem is that the tasks are shortened. Look at and for sufficient task answers and texts concerning this tasks. For example [Jay Pantone](http://jaypantone.com/courses/winter16math118/lecture-notes/lecture-notes-05.pdf). This offers You much more insight and understanding. On page 2 is already the answer.

Comment: Hi @user2432923, is there any other solutions to this task? Since the one you sent is explained shortoy, can you btw look at my comment below the answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The analysis of this sort of generating function's asymptotics is an exercise in partial fraction decomposition. Suppose we're trying to find the asymptotics of $P_n$ whose generating function $\sum_i P_ix^i$ is $\dfrac1{P(x)}$. If we can factor the polynomial $P(x)$ as $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$ (and all the roots are distinct), then we can write $\dfrac1{P(x)}$ as $\sum_i\dfrac{m_i}{x-r_i}$ for some constants $m_i$ (more on this later). We can then go the other direction, using the geometric series to write $P_n$ as $\sum_i \frac{m_i}{r_i}(r_i^{-1})^n$. If $r_1$ is the smallest root in absolute value, then this implies that $P_n=\frac{m_1}{r_1}(r_1^{-1})^n(1+O(\epsilon^n))$ for some $\epsilon\lt 1$. (There are very minor complications when the smallest roots are complex conjugates but that's not relevant here.)

In this case, we know that the polynomial $P(x)=1-(x+x^2+\ldots+x^{d-1})$ is positive at $x=0$ and negative at $x=1$ (as long as $d\gt 2$; if $d=2$ the analysis is trivial), so it has a root in $(0,1)$. What's more, since $P'(x)$ is negative on this interval, it has a single, simple root $\rho_{d-1}$ in the interval. (And in fact, all roots of $P()$ are simple since $\gcd(P, P')=1$.) Using [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#From_Rouch%C3%A9_theorem) applied to $(1-x)P(x) = 1-2x+x^d$, we can show that there are no other roots of $P(x)$ in the disc $x\lt 1$, so this root dominates the asymptotics; we have that $C_n=C(\xi_{d-1})^n$ for some constant $C$, where $\xi_{d-1}=\rho_{d-1}^{-1}$. Note that we can say this even without being able to write an explicit formula for $\xi_{d-1}$ (except in the first few cases, such as the Fibonacci numbers).

The next piece of the puzzle is to compute $C$; fortunately, there's a standard tool for this, the [residue method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method) — I'll leave the details of this to you.

Also, one small additional note: if you're curious, you can also examine the asymptotics of $\xi_d$ itself — specifically, the asymptotics as $d$ goes to infinity. It should be straightforward to find the limiting value (hint: what $x$ has $x+x^2+x^3+\ldots=1$?) but the rate of approach is a really nice problem.

A similar analysis can be done in principle for $[x^n]\left(xC(x)^2\right)$ $=[x^{n-1}]\left(C(x)^2\right)$, but it's substantially complicated by the fact that the root is no longer simple. Fortunately, there's another way of finding the asymptotics: you can use the equation for the coefficients of $C(x)^2$ in terms of the $C_n$ and then applying the asymptotic analysis of the $C_n$ to those terms. (You should find that each of the summands in the equation for the coefficients of $C(x)^2$ is comparable in size — see if you can figure out why.)

Comment: Hi, @Steven Stadnicki you approach makes a lot of sense, however I could not complete it ( to get part C)..my problem is with the asymptotics (since I did not use this approach before , so it would be very kind if you can show me how this is done).

Comment: Sure — I'll add it shortly when I have some spare time, but the brief version is that you decompose $P(x)$ via partial fractions, and a root $\xi$ of $P(x)$ corresponds to a term $(\xi-x)^{-1}$ in the partial fraction decomposition, which leads to a term $\Theta(\xi^{-n})$ in the asymptotics.

Comment: To which two funcrions you applied the Rouche's theorem?  I actually did not got the constant C so I said that $C_n \sim (\xi_{d-1})^n$, it that enough? And in the end when finding $[x^n] xC(x)^2$ i got by Caushy's formula, $[x^{-1}] C(x)^2= [x^{n-1}] \sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n}  c_n c_{n-j} x^n= \sum_{j=0}^{n} c_{n-1}c_{n-j-1}= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (\xi_{d-1} )^{2n-j-1} =\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\rho_{d-1}^ {-2n+j+1})$ so the expectation is not "nice",, sorry for my notes but it is difficulat to understand it when you don't see the full proof..@Steven Stadnicki

Comment: @Usermat I only applied Rouche's theorem to one function, the function $1-2x+x^d$. Your formula is wrong; remember that you're convolving so that the terms where you have $c_nc_{n-j}x^n$ should be e.g. $c_jc_{n-j}x^n$. I don't want to give the full proof since this _is_ an exercise and I don't want to give you every piece of it, but hopefully what I've posted should be enough to provide a guideline.

Comment: Hi @Steven Stadnicki  Hi  when finding the asymptotic of $[x^{n-1}]C(x)^2$i got by Caushy's formula, that the coefficient is $\sum_{j=0}^{n_1} C_j C_{n-j-1}$ so can I say/claim that its asymptotic is $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \rho_{d-1}^{-j} \rho_{d-1}^{-n+j+1}=C \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \rho_{d-1}^{-n+1}$ where C is a constant, but now the sum is not related to the index $j$ ? Then to take the proportion of the two asymptotics (of $C_n$ and this)?

Comment: @Usermat That's right; the term inside the summand isn't related to the index at all — which means that the value of the sum is just $n$ times that summand: $C\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\rho_{d-1}^{-n+1}$ $= Cn\rho_{d-1}^{-n+1}$...